# how to create a base class of groups in TestNG xml file

Tags: xml, selenium, automation, testng, functional-testing

Im trying to automate an application which involves 100's of test cases using Selenium Java with TestNg as testing framework . So my test cases are grouped in TestNG , But i have about 50 groups , So do i need to specify all my groups in TestNG XML file , or is there any alternative for this , any reusable or creating a base class of groups and invoking in the XML file .

Answer (score 1):

There is no all option as such.  But if you want to run everything then why not just specify the package - it would run all the tests inside the package.

You can have regex expressions as well to specify the groups if you follow a particular pattern for groups naming eg.

```
    <groups>
    <run>
      <include name="windows.*"/>
    </run>
  </groups>
```

One more thing that can be done is if you want all your groups to be executed but not the tests which do not fall in any groups then in the regex just keep .* along with package run.